# Programmatically get WiFi Gateway, DNS info

Tags: ios, dns

I am able to get the wifi IP address information from a code that i found online:

Is it possible to identify the DNS & gateway information as well?
Any code that does it?
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done by using this code

```
#include <resolv.h>

#include <dns.h>
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h>    
#include<stdlib.h>    
#include<sys/socket.h>    
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr , inet_ntoa , ntohs etc
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<unistd.h>   


-(void) get_dns_servers
{
    res_state res = malloc(sizeof(struct __res_state));
    int result = res_ninit(res);
    if(result==0)
    {
        NSLog(@"No of DNS IP : %d",res->nscount);
        for ( int i= 0; i < res->nscount; i++)
        {
            NSString *s = [NSString stringWithUTF8String :  inet_ntoa(res->nsaddr_list[i].sin_addr)];
            NSLog(@"DNS ip : %@",s);
            [server_DNS addObject:s];
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: I got this: " Use of undeclared identifier 'server_DNS' " for last line.[ server_DNS addObject:s];

Comment: That will be a NSMutableArray for collecting the list of servers.